# Watir-webdrive how to automate google place autocomplete

Tags: ruby, autocomplete, google-api, watir-webdriver

We are using this google API https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete and I would like to automate the test case to select a specific address.

```
<fieldset class="control-group">
<a class="button small grey search-again" style="display: none;" href="#"> Erneut versuchen </a>
<input class="address-search" type="text" data-required="true" placeholder="Geben Sie Ihre Adresse ein" autocomplete="off">
```

this is the text field that needs to be filled.
I tried

```
@address_page.address_line1 = line1 
text_field(:address, :class => 'address-search')
```

but it just open the list of suggestions and doesn't select the one the I gave in input and I have this error

```
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)
      [remote server] file:///var/folders/zg/1303qv_56kjc0r43rpb9h0b40000gp/T/webdriver-profile20141020-26884-1it1xd2/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10816:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_'
```

Ant suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: After you have typed into the text field, how are you selecting the item from the autocomplete list? Is that where you are getting the visibility exception (ie exactly which command is generating that exception)?

Comment: it is that what I am not able to do, how I can select the item in the list that is opening?

Answer (score 1):

When working with the Google autocomplete field, you will need to:

1. Type something into the text field
2. Wait for the list of suggestions to appear. This is to avoid the possibility that Watir tries to interact with the suggestions before they have loaded.
3. Click one of the div elements that represent a suggestion.

Here is a working example using the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 example page:

```
# Go to the page
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto('http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html')

# For the test page, the places autocomplete is in an iframe
iframe = browser.div(id: 'gc-content').iframe

# Get the autocomplete field
autocomplete = iframe.text_field(id: 'pac-input')

# Type something into the autocomplete field
autocomplete.set('Aus')

# Wait for the list of suggestions to be displayed
suggestion_menu = iframe.div(class: 'pac-container')
suggestion_menu.wait_until_present

# Click one of the suggestions, in this case, we clicked the second suggestion
suggestion_menu.div(class: 'pac-item', index: 1).click

# Check that the autocomplete value is updated
p autocomplete.value
#=> "Australian Capital Territory, Australia"
```

Note that you may have to tweak the script for your specific implementation. For example, the text field id may not be 'pac-input'. However, the general concept should apply to this and many other autocomplete fields.